# How can I retrieve location of an UIElement on silverlight bing maps control?

Tags: silverlight, location, bing-maps, uielement

I put image on the silverlight bing map control like this :

```
MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayer();
this.myMap.Children.Add(mapLayer);

Image image = new Image();
BitmapImage btm = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/myAssembly;component/Images/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
image.Source = btm;
LocationRect rect = new LocationRect(new Location(10, 12), new Location(55, 55));

mapLayer.AddChild(image, rect);
```

This is working fine. But I can't find how to retrieve the location somewhere else in my code. I try :

```
var loc = MapLayer.GetPosition(image) --> Always returning null !!!
```

The maplayer object doesn't have any methods to get children locations and I can't calculate the position with `mapLayer.ParentMap.TryViewportPointToLocation` because the image `Width` and `Height` properties are always 0 (why that ??).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the location if you save it somewhere before adding. Keep these in some variables somewhere.

```
new Location(10, 12), new Location(55, 55)
```